# Simple Linear Algebra Question about consistency of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I just wanted to confirm.

Can we say that a system of linear equation, which is consistent, must have infinitely many solutions if there are more number of equations than variables?

I'm guessing that this is true because the rank of the matrix cannot be equal to the number of variables. (Maximum rank is the number of linear equations. )

Comment: I think you may have this backwards.  If a system is consistent and has more variables than equations, *then* there must be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: True. Its a type error by me. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x-y=0, x+y=1, 2x+2y=2$. There are three equations, two variables but one solution.